# How to convert to json only data that can be converted?

Tags: json, swift, string, parsing

How to convert in json only the data in string that can be converted? (in this example, only window.digitalData data)

```
let str = "window.digitalData = {"version":"1.0","page":..}; 
           if (typeof listing != 'undefined'
               && listing.items.length > 0...
           }"

guard let jsonData = str.data(using: .utf8) else { return }
guard let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData, options: []) as? [String: Any] else { return }
```

Comment: Extract the desired JSON part with Regex or (NS)Scanner and deserialize it.

Comment: So you want to give a string, and find inside it all possible JSON? Or is it always after  `window.digitalData = ` and before...? That's not how it should work. Do you have an API? Where are you getting the data from?

Comment: I have a string and in it I need to convert only what can be converted. No, I don’t have an API. I am parsing a site page.